# antenna gain data 3D matlab pattern

Tags: excel, matlab

I have excel antenna gain data  in horizontal and vertical. How can I plot 3D pattern in matlab with thise data like image I add.

[image]

Excel data is [antenna gain data](http://we.tl/9xhs3XjnSb)  in this link.

Horizontal data like this (360x1) =[14 13,9 13,9 13,8 ........14]
Vertical  data like this (360x1) =[14 13,9 13,9 13,8 ........14]

Comment: have you tried something already?

Comment: You have insufficient data. To make 3D gain `surf` plot, you need to have information for each combination of azimuth and elevation angles. You data provides only data for 0 elevation and arbitrary azimuth `(0,theta)` and for o azimuth and arbitrary elevation `(phi,0)`. But to make plot as one on the picture you provided you need data for, say, `(45, 45)` and so on,

Comment: in this link http://leleivre.com/notes_AntennaRange.html  Azimuth, Elevation and 3D has been plotted . But I could not understand which or what kind of  data they used.

Comment: This picture: http://leleivre.com/images/antenna_azel.png shows how to conduct measurements. Each circle corresponds to the measurements at fixed elevation angle. At each elevation angle you would get the slices similar to http://leleivre.com/images/antenna_azimuth_plot.png . Finally, you would have three matrices for Az/El angles and gain, all with the same sizes. Az/El matrices would form meshgrid. Finally, you use `sph2cart` function to create `x y z` matrices which you would be able to plot using `surf` or `mesh`

Comment: Hi brainkz ,
I could not understandant  that you  wrote "you would have three matrices for Az/El angles and gain". can you shed light on with example.